# WARNING: Can't resolve .param in LTspice

Tags: ltspice, simulation, buck

I am going to simulate buck converter using current mode control. I followed the circuit 2-80 from book
Switch-Mode Power Supplies: SPICE Simulations and Practical Designs, second edition written by Basso.
Unfortunately, I get an error from LTSpice **WARNING: Can't resolve .param gi**

does anybody knows how I can fix this error?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

All the `.param` definitions are evaluated prior to simulation start, because they need to be available in the schematic for the duration of the simulation. For this reason you can't evaluate `.param`s that involve time-dependent quantities: `gr`, `gi1`, `gi2`, `Dprim` and `D0` (or `DO`). There are ready-made examples, and not only in LTspice. Best take those instead of making your own, at least until you learn more about the tool you are using.